# RedirectToAction not working along with call to same controller's action through $.ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am calling a controller's action method called RedirectToHome through an ajax call. Inside that action method I am using RedirectToAction to excute the Index method of Spa controller. This redirect is not working even though the code gets successfully executed. I assume this is happening because RedirectToHome is called through ajax call. That's why I also tried calling the Index method too using ajax call when the ajax call for first request is successful. But even through second ajax call, I see that Index method does gets called but the view is never rendered. There are no errors in the console.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url' + "Account/RedirectToHome",
            data: { email: userEmail },
            success: function (data) {
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url' + "Spa/Index",
                    data: { isAuthenticated:true,email: userEmail },
                        success: function () {
                    }
                    });
            }
    });

 public ActionResult RedirectToHome(string email)
    {
        if (ValidateDomain(email))
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Spa", new { isAuthenticated = true, email = email });
        else
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");

    }
```

Comment: If your intention is to redirect the user request why are you doing ajax? Ajax is for partial page updates.

Comment: Because I want to pass javascript variable (userEmail in above code), to the action method I had to call it through ajax else I would have not used that.

Comment: Well a simple `ActionLink` with a query string will work.

Comment: Agree, but the kind of UI I have now, I cannot give an action link to the user

Comment: Show me where `userEmail` is coming from.

Comment: I am using Google+ Sign In in the app, I get that value from google+ api in javascript.

Comment: Ok, there is a way to dynamically add js variables to query strings. It should be as simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Url.Action()`, not `Spa/Index`.

```
$.ajax({
            data: { email: userEmail },
            success: function (data) {
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Spa")',
                    data: { isAuthenticated:true,email: userEmail },
                        success: function () {

                      //use your redirect code here, not in action
                      if(result.isValidDomain)
                      {
                        document.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Spa")/' + '?isAuthenticated=' + true;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        document.location.href = '@Url.Action("ExternalLoginFailure", "Controller")';
                      }

                    }
                    });
            }
    });
```

Comment: You can remove / you have used in '@Url.Action("Index", "Spa")/'. Also I do not want the url to show those query string parameters. Those are only used within the method.

Comment: I am thinking of storing those values in Session, so that I don't have to pass them in querystrings.

Comment: document.location.href does render the view, so I am marking your answer.

Comment: Thanks for marking, but if redirect works, it is not possible view render doesn't work. If it not rendering, are you sure that action fires after redirecting?

Comment: RedirectToAction does not work because RedirectToHome method is called using ajax. Redirects don't work with ajax requests. But with document.location.href, we are actually calling the action method.